# How to correctly update my layout (based weight attribute) with cardview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I am working to update my app with `CardCiew` widget, I already update some simple layout.

The problem that when I use a `LinearLayout` set with `layout_weight` attribute I get a different result I want.

### layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/technologie_ll_item">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_logo_technologie"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    app:border_width="2dp"
                    app:border_color="#99069d78"
                    android:src="@drawable/after"
                    android:paddingLeft="0dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_nom_technologie"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Orthodontics"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/indic" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

## Result

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this can help you.

## Approach 1

(Note i have changed your `CircleImageView` with a `Imageview` so i could make it works without errors ;))

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/technologie_ll_item">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_logo_technologie"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_nom_technologie"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Orthodontics" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

As you can see you will have 1 `LinearLayout` which `android:weightSum` is 10 (just to make the proportion better) that holds the 3 components. The first `LinearLayout` container that holds the `CircleImageView` (aka `ImageView` in my code) will have a `android:layout_weight` of 2, the text will have a `android:layout_weight` of 7, and the arrow container will have a `android:layout_weight` of 1.

Maybe you can get rid of the `LinearLayout` that holds the arrow, and set the weight directly in the `ImageView`, i think that if you apply the arrow as `android:src` it will be resized respecting the scale of the image given, but I am not sure about this now.

### Approach 2:

Another solution will be the `RelativeLayout`, as the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/technologie_ll_item">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <!-- CircleImageView here -->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_logo_technologie"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp" />

            <!-- Arrow drawable here -->
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/arrow"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <!-- Text here, between circle and arrow -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_nom_technologie"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_logo_technologie"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/arrow"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Orthodontics" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

With this you remove the `LinearLayout` and you will have only 3 components, maybe better for perfomance.

Hope some of this will help you mate.

Regards!